# Angularjs use factory value inside one more factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have one java script file with two factories which makes http calls to web api. I want to use one factory value output inside another factory. Below is my first factory

```
myapp.factory('sadadpaymentapi', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 'cfg', 'ScrollFunction', 'leaselisting','$q', function ($http, $cookieStore, cfg, ScrollFunction, leaselisting,$q) {
    var sadadpaymentapiobject = {};
    var baseurl = cfg.Baseurl;
    var LoginID = $cookieStore.get("LoginID");
    var cookiePreferredLanguage = $cookieStore.get('PreferredLanguage');
    var urlapi = baseurl + "api/ServiceRequest/CreateRSSedad/";
    sadadpaymentapiobject.callsadad = function (PaymentType) {
        var request = {
            url: urlapi,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                SRActivityID: LoginID,
                PaymentType: PaymentType,
                PaymentAmount: "100" //Need to get value from another factory
            },
            headers: ScrollFunction.getheaders()
        };
        return $http(request);
    }
    return sadadpaymentapiobject;
}]);
```

Below is another factory where i can get value for PaymentAmount parameter in the above factory.

```
myapp.factory('leaselisting', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 'cfg', 'ScrollFunction','$q', function ($http, $cookieStore, cfg, ScrollFunction,$q) {
    var leaselistingobject = {};
    var baseurl = cfg.Baseurl;
    var LoginID = $cookieStore.get("LoginID");
    var cookiePreferredLanguage = $cookieStore.get('PreferredLanguage');
    leaselistingobject.getValue = function () {
        var requestObj = {
                                url: baseurl + "api/ServiceRequest/GetROLSPSRLeaseList/",
                                method:'POST',
                                data: {
                                    LoginID: LoginID,
                                    AccountNumber: $cookieStore.get("AccountNumber")
                                },
                                headers: ScrollFunction.getheaders()
                    };
        return $http(requestObj).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
    return leaselistingobject;
}]);
```

When i inject like  PaymentAmount: leaselisting.getValue() and if i try to display in the console value injected        `console.log(leaselisting.getValue());` I get Promise {$$state etc. I have attached screen shot. What i need is from the above figure variable AccountNumber. 
[image: Nesting Factory]

I am trying to do in the first api,   PaymentAmount: "100" instead of hard coding i want to get it from other factory. May i know how to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`leaselisting` factory has method `getValue` that call asyc call and resolves it.

So you can write:

```
// ...
var request = {
        url: urlapi,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            SRActivityID: LoginID,
            PaymentType: PaymentType,
            PaymentAmount: leaselisting.getValue();
        },
 // ...
```

This is a <kbd>[Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5qo1cjv/)</kbd> that simulates your case. Since second async call is based on 1st one, I would use Promise chain. In my case I simulate async call with `$timeout` that returns some part of address (in your case its `PaymentAmount`), resolve it with promise and call other Promise `$http`

```
app.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope, sadadpaymentapi) {

    $scope.alertSwap = function () {           
        $scope.data = sadadpaymentapi.getData();    
    }; 
});

app.$inject = ['$scope', 'leaselisting'];

app.factory('leaselisting', ['$timeout','$q',  function($timeout, $q) {    

       var leaselistingobject = {
            getValue: function () {              
               var deferred = $q.defer();               
               $timeout(function(){                  
                return {address: 'Singapore, SG, Singapore, 153 Bukit Batok Street 1'};
               }, 3000).then(function(val){
               deferred.resolve(val); 
               });              
                return deferred.promise;
            }

       };       
        return leaselistingobject;
}]);


app.factory('sadadpaymentapi', ['$http','$q','leaselisting', function($http, $q,leaselisting) {  

       var leaselistingobject = {
            getData: function () {    

               var URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=';  

               return leaselisting.getValue().then(function(result){

                URL = URL + result.address + '&sensor=true';

                 return $http({method: 'GET', url: URL})
                }).then(function (response) {
                   return response.data;
                 });
            }

       };       
        return leaselistingobject;
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question and added screen shot what i get when i inject. If you see image i attached you can see one field AccountNumber which i want to assign it to PaymentAmount. So How can do this?

Comment: Also when i do  var data = leaselisting.getValue();
        console.log(data.data); i get undefined. Struggling to fix this since two weeks.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole ill post u shrtly the demo

Comment: Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Thank you. In leaselisting   i did not understand return {address: 'Singapore, SG, Singapore, 153 Bukit Batok Street 1'}; and where should i put my request object?

Comment: Please can you explain me   URL = URL + result.address + '&sensor=true';
                return $http({ method: 'GET', url: URL }) these two lines? Thanks

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole its only demo. we bring value from other factory, append to existing string and make http GET call

Answer (score 5):

Inject the factory to the second factory and the rest is same as how you would do in controller,

```
myapp.factory('leaselisting', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 'cfg', 'ScrollFunction','$q','sadadpaymentapi', function ($http, $cookieStore, cfg, ScrollFunction,$q,sadadpaymentapi) {
```

Comment: Thank you. I already injected.   PaymentAmount: ? what should i write here! Something like leaselisting.getValue?

Comment: assign the value to a variable and use sadadpaymentapi.PaymentAmount

Comment: @Sajeetharan the `sadadpaymentapi` function argument should not be a string literal

Comment: May be Something wrong u understood from my question. PaymentAmount: ?????? In ? should i place leaselisting.getValue?

Comment: PaymentAmount: leaselisting.getValue();

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan. I edited my question and added screen shot what i get when i inject. If you see image i attached you can see one field AccountNumber which i want to assign it to PaymentAmount. So How can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do like below in your controller :

```
 leaselisting.getValue().then(function(response){
         //you get account number here and pass it in another factory
           var accountNumber = response.data.AccountNumber;
          sadadpaymentapi.callsadad (accountNumber ).then(function(response){
                 //Do with your final response
          });
    });
```

and Factory code :

```
myapp.factory('leaselisting', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 'cfg', 'ScrollFunction','$q', function ($http, $cookieStore, cfg, ScrollFunction,$q) {
        var leaselistingobject = {};
        var baseurl = cfg.Baseurl;
        var LoginID = $cookieStore.get("LoginID");
        var cookiePreferredLanguage = $cookieStore.get('PreferredLanguage');
        leaselistingobject.getValue = function () {
            var requestObj = {
                                    url: baseurl + "api/ServiceRequest/GetROLSPSRLeaseList/",
                                    method:'POST',
                                    data: {
                                        LoginID: LoginID,
                                        AccountNumber: accountNumber
                                    },
                                    headers: ScrollFunction.getheaders()
                        };
            return $http(requestObj)
        }
        return leaselistingobject;
    }]);
```

make sure you have injected both of your factories in your controller